# JQuery selector for href containing '#'

Tags: jquery

Is it possible to create a JQuery selector that gets all anchors whose href attributes contains a `#`?

```
var localNavLinks = $('a[href=".*#.*"]');
```

Comment: `var localNavLinks = $('a[href*="#"]');` `*` for contains `^` for start with `$` for ends with .. I highly recommend to read about [Selectors Here](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/the-30-css-selectors-you-must-memorize--net-16048)

Comment: This is my go-to CSS attribute selector reference https://css-tricks.com/attribute-selectors/

Answer (score 0):

According to @Mohamed-Yousef reply, `*` operator will fit you with the condition of containing `#`:

```js
$('a[href*="#"]').css('background-color', '#CCCCCC');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h4>Matched anchor will change background color:</h4>
<p><a href="#a">Anchor</a></p>
<p><a href="https://stackoverflow.com">URL</a></p>
<p><a href="https://stackoverflow.com#a">URL with anchor</a></p>
```

JSfiddle Example: https://jsfiddle.net/jennifergoncalves/jf66oc77/